# Obtain value of xml node and manipulate it using as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a large XML File with four nodes, using this to create an interactive pyramid style infograph. The trouble is I want to be able to manipulate the colour of the bars when the year is over a specific value within the record set so this is what I have got so far.

*xml file

```
<dataset>
<source></source>
<extent></extent>
<scaleFac></scaleFac>
<recordSet year="1982" popTotal="1544545">
<m> //Male
<rd></rd>
<f> //Female
<rd></rd>
```

ActionScript

After Loading in the xml file I created a variable to hold the recordset year value which is what I need to use.

```
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(evt.target.data);
//populates metadat fields
seriesLength=xmlData.recordSet.length();
yearRecord=xmlData.recordSet.text();
```

then I created a function called, modify year which is where my problem lies. I have tried created a simple if else statement where when the value(Year) is more than 2013 we should change the colour of the bars.

```
function modifyYear(){

var mcF:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var mcFGraphics:Graphics = mcF.graphics;

    if (yearRecord>2013){

        mcFGraphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF,1);
    }

    else {
        mcFGraphics.beginFill(0x660066,1);
    }
};
```

I am not sure how to check to see if the year record is more than the specific value. Iam pretty new to actionscript so any help would be greatfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your problem correctly. 
If you confused of how to get an attribute value from the xml node, then here it is:

```
var yearRecord:String = xmlData.recordSet.attribute("year");
```

If you are just not sure about how to compare two values if one of them is string and another is integer, then you have to convert String to int:

```
if( int(yearRecord) > 2013 )
{...}
```

Try it, please, and don't hesitate to ask, if you don't understand smth.
And good luck with AS :)

Comment: Thanks very much, the conditional statement seems to work correctly. Now I just have one more question I want the bars to change colours when it passes 2013. So should the above work using mcFGraphics.beginFill or is there more to it. An easier way could be potentially just a note that becomes visible on this condition any help would be grateful